# Powershell: Sleeping mid-pipeline

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to add a (relatively) small pause between two sets of code because the second half needs to have the first half executed successfully prior to running -- but PowerShell sometimes gets a little ahead of itself and proceeds before the previous command completed entirely.

Just for context, this is the code I'm working with:

```
Initialize-Disk -PassThru -PartitionStyle GPT -Confirm:$false `
      | New-Partition -DriveLetter D -UseMaximumSize
```

Often this fails because the drive isn't completely initialized by the time PowerShell executes the `New-Partition`.

Typically I'd use something like:

```
Initialize-Disk -PassThru -PartitionStyle GPT -Confirm:$false
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
New-Partition -DriveLetter D -UseMaximumSize
```

However the problem is that the output object of `Initialize-Disk` is lost and `New-Partition` doesn't get an input object.

I tried putting the `Start-Sleep` in the pipeline:

```
Initialize-Disk -PassThru -PartitionStyle GPT -Confirm:$false `
      | Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 `
      | New-Partition -DriveLetter D -UseMaximumSize
```

...but it throws an exception as `Start-Sleep` doesn't know how to make sense of the input object (which is fair enough).

```
Start-Sleep : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline 
input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.ps1:104 char:87
+ ... nfirm:$false | Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 `
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_Disk (Obje...11E2-93F2-0...):PSObject) [Start-Sleep], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartSleepCommand
```

---

**tl;dr:** How can I add a pause in my code whilst keeping the output object of the preceding cmdlet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using background job:

```
Initialize-Disk -PassThru -PartitionStyle GPT -Confirm:$false -asjob |
wait-job | receive-job | New-Partition -DriveLetter D -UseMaximumSize
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try(untested):

```
Initialize-Disk -PassThru -PartitionStyle GPT -Confirm:$false |
    % { Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 | Out-Null; $_ } |
    New-Partition -DriveLetter D -UseMaximumSize
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sleep the given number of seconds for each item in the pipeline you can use `ForEach-Object` as [Graimer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15633887/1630171) suggested. If you want to sleep just the given number of seconds regardless of the number of items in the pipeline, you have to break up the pipeline:

```
$disks = Initialize-Disk -PassThru -PartitionStyle GPT -Confirm:$false
sleep 2
$disks | New-Partition -DriveLetter D -UseMaximumSize
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (similar to another answer):

```
New-Partition … | ForEach-Object { Start-Sleep -s 3; $_ | Format-Volume … }
```